# How do I write to an Android application's database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I ran into a problem developing an Android application.

When I read a database file in a folder in the application's files, and write to the DB, it worked. It didn't work on a real Android phone.

I don't know why it couldn't write the database into the phone. Does the application need more permissions other than these?:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I doubt this is it, the emulator and phone share the same permission policy. What error are you getting? You can try to catch the exception and display it on screen.

Comment: I couldn't write the database into the real android phone by my application.My application need to use my own database.Do you hava any ideas about using external database ?

Comment: I think you are describing issue wrongly. May be some other issue is there. Did you got any exasperation?

Comment: Add the full StackTrace to your question. Also, add some Source Code (but don't simply dump all code here!)

Answer (score 1):

For a decent tutorial on using Android's built-in support for SQLite check out the [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html).  You don't need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for database support, btw.